# QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS dependencies issue

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake, rcc

All

I have Qt project which contains **.ts-file** and **.qrc-file** containing reference to generated **.qm-file**. We do not store .qm-files in our version control system. The issue here is that when I check out source code and run "make", I'm getting error

```
RCC: Error in 'CoreGeneral.qrc': Cannot find file 'core.general_en.qm'
```

I created updateqm.pri files to get .qm files generated before build, this file I include to my .pro files

```
!contains(QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS, updateqm) {
    updateqm.input         = TRANSLATIONS
    updateqm.output        = ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.qm
    updateqm.commands      = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/lrelease -idbased ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -qm ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.qm
    updateqm.CONFIG       += no_link target_predeps
    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += updateqm
    PRE_TARGETDEPS        += compiler_updateqm_make_all }
```

But again, I'm getting this error, though .qm files eventually get generated.
Compile output looks like this

```
 C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012\bin\lrelease -idbased core.general_en.ts -qm core.general_en.qm
    C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012\bin\uic.exe PSGHTMLDisplay.ui -o GeneratedFiles\ui_PSGHTMLDisplay.h
    C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012\bin\rcc.exe -name CoreGeneral CoreGeneral.qrc -o GeneratedFiles\qrc_CoreGeneral.cpp
RCC: Error in 'CoreGeneral.qrc': Cannot find file 'core.general_en.qm'

Updating 'core.general_en.qm'...
    Generated 108 translation(s) (0 finished and 108 unfinished)
```

So, for me it looks like RCC starts processing .qrc file before lrelease finished generating .qm-files.

Is there any approach to avoid this issue?

**P.S.** I tried using QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS to create pre-build event that will be generating .qm-files before any other target will be started but it didn't work for me. I used approach described here [enter link description here](http://blog.mgsxx.com/?p=2180)

Briefly, the approach of creating pre-build event is like below

```
    # создаем файл-заглушку
!exists($$OUT_PWD/.beforebuild) {
  system(@echo aaa > $$system_path($${OUT_PWD}/.beforebuild))
}

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += before_build makefilehook

makefilehook.target = $(MAKEFILE)
makefilehook.depends = .beforebuild

POST_TARGETDEPS += .beforebuild

before_build.target = .beforebuild
before_build.depends = FORCE
before_build.commands = @echo our command
```